# Syntactic error while laying down an UPDATE statement with a JOIN operation

Tags: mysql, sql

I am updating a table based on a value in another table but I cannot figure out why it is throwing an error at the `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE sn
SET sn.delay = 'Yes'
FROM arh ar
INNER JOIN tbl_salesactivity_new sn ON sn.shipment = ar.shipment_id
WHERE ar.ardelay > '0';
```

Comment: That syntax can be valid in some databases an invalid in other ones. Which database are you using?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Comment: Mysql.  I should have thought to mention it my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL the correct syntax to update a table using a `JOIN` operation is following:

```
UPDATE     tbl_salesactivity_new sn
INNER JOIN arh ar
        ON sn.shipment = ar.shipment_i
       AND ar.ardelay > '0'
SET sn.delay = 'Yes'
```

To learn more about this syntax, check the examples found at this [link](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/).

---

**EDIT**. Adding another option >> moving the condition in the `WHERE` clause (*ysth*'s suggestion)

```
UPDATE     tbl_salesactivity_new sn
INNER JOIN arh ar
        ON sn.shipment = ar.shipment_i
SET sn.delay = 'Yes'
WHERE ar.ardelay > '0'
```

Comment: Thank you and thank you for the link.  I appreciate your time and assistance today.

Comment: moving the ardelay condition into the join works but is not necessary; it could have stayed as a WHERE clause after SET

Comment: That's correct. Take into account ysth hint @user3465081

Comment: One last problem.  IT is running but it is taking a really long time.  Any thoughts on a better way to update the initial table.  The table i am updating might have  different rows with the same shipment_id.

Comment: One idea is using a index on the columns you're joining on, though this problem may require a better understanding of the tables schema and content. @user3465081

Comment: Thank you.  I marked it answered.